# Using JavaMailSender in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, smtp

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I've created this service to send emails

```
@Service
public class MailClient {

    protected static final Logger looger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    private MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder;

    @Autowired
    public MailClient(JavaMailSender mailSender, MailContentBuilder mailContentBuilder) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.mailContentBuilder = mailContentBuilder;
    }

    //TODO: in a properties
    public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
        MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom("nunito@calzada.com");
            messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
            messageHelper.setSubject("Sample mail subject");
            String content = mailContentBuilder.build(message);
            messageHelper.setText(content, true);
        };
        try {
            if (looger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                looger.debug("sending email to " + recipient);
            }
            mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            looger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this error when Init the SpringBootApplication

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailProperties@1e94ed11 failed:

    Property: spring.mail.defaultEncoding
    Value: UTF-8 
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.nio.charset.Charset' for property 'defaultEncoding'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.nio.charset.Charset]


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

and this is my application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=localhost
spring.mail.port=25 
spring.mail.username= 
spring.mail.password= 
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.defaultEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have comments in the same line as the property. Everycomment must be in its own line starting with '#'
The error message shows

```
Value: 25 # SMTP server port
```

so the value is the String '25 # SMTP server port' and cannot be converted into an Integer.

Move the comment in its own line, above the property :

```
# SMTP server port
spring.mail.port=25
```